# Empty Row not shown when table is rendered as pdf

Tags: visualforce, html, rerender

I have a HTML table in vf email template. in one or the row i wanted to add empty row so i added below code:

```
<tr height="20"></tr>
```

Now this works fine & i see the empty row in table:
[image]

But when i Render this table as PDF then this empty row is not visible. 
[image]

So how do i enforce this empty row in renderedas pdf table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do it.. either by tweaking the CSS or by adding in empty content inside the row.. either way you need to have a column that spans the entire row..

you can place a empty div inside the row and set the height of the div instead of setting it on the table row..

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" >
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                First Row
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="height:20px"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Last Row
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

you can refer this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225196/prevent-collapse-of-empty-rows-in-html-table-via-css/42225797) for other options